# http://localhost:8080/ macbook air m1 - vs code debugger cannot launch me to this localhost

Tags: localhost

when I try debug in vs code

I click launch in chrome

error message in chrome is

---

This site can’t be reached localhost refused to connect.
Try:

```
Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

---

Why can I never connect to this local host address what am I doing wrong and what is the solution?

Thanks!!!

Tried to turn off the firewall, start the apache server in the terminal again, restart computer, tried edge, tried mac, tried adding a new configuration is JSON file...

I was expecting it to reach the local host 8080 ...

Comment: thanks, new to Stack! Figured it out, I did not have node.js installed, when I installed node.js. I was able to access the local host.

Answer (score 0):

When you get that error, it means that when you tried to connect, there was not a process listening, so no connection could be made.

When this happens with localhost (or any remote server you admin), you should start by trying to confirm whether anything is listening.

On my M1:

```
 % netstat -a | grep LISTEN
tcp6       0      0  *.commplex-main        *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp4       0      0  *.commplex-main        *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0  *.afs3-fileserver      *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp4       0      0  *.afs3-fileserver      *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp4       0      0  *.kerberos             *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0  *.kerberos             *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp4       0      0  *.rfb                  *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0  *.rfb                  *.*                    LISTEN
```

I don't know what those services are, so lets show the actual port numbers:

```
netstat -an | grep LISTEN
tcp6       0      0  *.5000                 *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp4       0      0  *.5000                 *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0  *.7000                 *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp4       0      0  *.7000                 *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp4       0      0  *.88                   *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0  *.88                   *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp4       0      0  *.5900                 *.*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0  *.5900                 *.*                    LISTEN     

% ssh localhost
ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused
```

(NOTE: ssh uses port 22 by default, port 22 wasn't in use according to `netstat`, so you get the error.)

Comment: thank you! I did not have node.js installed on my new laptop, once I installed it I was able to access the localhost